# Zend 2 annotations and file validators

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is it possible to use file validation classes with form annotations?

```
/**
 * @Form\Name("profile_avatar")
 * @Form\Type("Zend\Form\Element\File")
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Your avatar"})
 * @Form\Validator({"name":"Zend\Validator\File\IsImage"})
 */
public $profile_avatar;
```

With code above form is always valid even if you send non-image file.

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to use only "IsImage" as name... I had similar problem with Hostname valuidator. I actually didn't solved it because I can't get the options working...

Comment: Are you sure that doing this would solve the issue? This seems more like a comment to me.